# mix phx.gen.html generator immediately causes compile errors?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm making a new Phoenix app for the first time in about a year, and trying to get a handle on everything that's changed with regards to context etc.

My first order of business is creating a database table where I can track email signups, so I put this command in:

`mix phx.gen.html Signups Email emails email:string name:string data:text`

And then I put the new routes in my router.ex. But even before I can migrate, I get an error:

```
== Compilation error in file lib/appname/views/email_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/appname/views/email_view.ex:2: module AppnameWeb is not loaded and could not be found
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
    lib/appname/views/email_view.ex:2: AppnameWeb.EmailView (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:121: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

I have `Appname.Web` other places in my app, but the generator created a new module called AppnameWeb that doesn't seem to be loaded anywhere?

If I do a find and replace in my project to Appname.Web to AppnameWeb, it lets me migrate but still fails to load the new emails index page.

```
Request: GET /emails
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Appname.EmailController.init/1 is undefined (module Appname.EmailController is not available)
        Appname.EmailController.init(:index)
        (appname) web/router.ex:1: anonymous fn/1 in Appname.Router.__match_route__/4
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router.ex:278: Phoenix.Router.__call__/1
        (appname) lib/appname/endpoint.ex:1: Appname.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
        (appname) lib/plug/debugger.ex:99: Appname.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (appname) lib/appname/endpoint.ex:1: Appname.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) /Users/user/Dev/appname/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

So am I supposed to have both Appname.Web and AppnameWeb? I'm not sure what's supposed to go where any more, and the fact that the generator generates broken code isn't helping...

Comment: Did you generate the app using some beta/rc version of Phoenix 1.3? I think the `.Web` naming structure was there in a beta/rc but the dot was removed in the final version. You'll probably have to change the `.Web` to `Web` everywhere as that's what 1.3 generators use.

Comment: Damn Dogbert, you are always faster than me :D Anyways, the `.Web` to `Web` change happened between rc2 and rc3 of Phoenix 1.3 and it was also my first guess that some part of the app was created prior to `1.3-rc3`.

Comment: @Dogbert & Phillipp Thanks! Yeah I generated the app a few days ago to try out Distillery/Edeliver. I guess that's what I get for using a release candidate version :D Thanks for your help both of you.

Comment: @Phillipp Actually now that I look at it again, I only created the app a few days ago, and the latest release candidate version (rc3) came out 2 months ago... When I created a new app just now I have the exact same problem. "module TestappWeb is not loaded and could not be found"

Comment: Did you install `phx.new` a few days ago (using `mix archive.install ...`)? The generator is not automatically updated. You might have installed it 2 months ago.

Comment: @Dogbert I did a `mix phoenix.new -v` and made sure I got `Phoenix v1.3.0-rc.3` before creating another test app where I got the same error.

Comment: Looks like you have `use AppnameWeb, :view` instead of `use Appname.Web, :view` in the `email_view.ex` in the first place. Then you worsened the situation by renaming.